# Using IF in BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

**Case**: I have Sales table in BQ and item_num column contains values 1, -1 and 0. I want to count how many cases I have for each value.

Tried a simple query below, but count returns exactly the same number for each case.. What I am missing?

```
SELECT 
count(if(item_num > 0,1, 0)) as buysplus,
count(if(item_num < 0,1, 0)) as buysminus,
count(if(item_num = 0,1, 0)) as buyszero
from MyShop.Sales
```

thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(item_num > 0, 1, 0)) AS buysplus,
  SUM(IF(item_num < 0, 1, 0)) AS buysminus,
  SUM(IF(item_num = 0, 1, 0)) AS buyszero
FROM MyShop.Sales
```

or even less verbose version of it:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(item_num > 0) AS buysplus,
  SUM(item_num < 0) AS buysminus,
  SUM(item_num = 0) AS buyszero
FROM MyShop.Sales
```

this will give yo result like below

```
buysplus    buysminus   buyszero     
4           2           3
```

Another option would be transposed version of it

```
SELECT 
  item_num AS buys,
  COUNT(1) AS volume
FROM MyShop.Sales
GROUP BY 1
```

with the result as below

```
 buys        volume  
 0          3    
 1          4    
-1          2
```

Comment: I would add that in BigQuery's Standard SQL mode, you can simplify the counting (which some people find more intuitive, if less portable).  Instead of `SUM(IF(item_num > 0,1,0))` you can use `COUNTIF(item_num > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `COUNTIF`, just like @justbeez sugests. According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#countif)

> *Returns the count of `TRUE` values for `expression`*

So applied to your case would look like:

```sql
SELECT 
  COUNTIF(item_num > 0) as buysplus,
  COUNTIF(item_num < 0) as buysminus,
  COUNTIF(item_num = 0) as buyszero
FROM MyShop.Sales
```

You don't save a lot of code, but *count* is a little bit more idiomatic than *sum* IMHO.